# my database table is not updating after modifying

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am new to PHP. When I am trying to update or modify my form then it is not getting updated in the phpmyadmin database. I am using AJAX, jQuery, and PHP. I am badly stuck her so can anyone guide me that how to solve this issue. Following are the codes guys..
update_details.php

```
    <form id="form6" name="form6" method="post">
  <div class="row">
    <h4 style="font-size: 16px;padding-left: 15px;"><b>Benefits Delivered by Local People from Plantation Felling:</b></h4><br>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div align="right" style="padding-right: 10px;">
        <label style="font-weight:300;font-size: 15px;margin-top:5px; ">Dependence of Local People on the Site:
        </label>
        <select name="dependence_of_local_people" id="dependence_of_local_people" style="width:30%;height: 30px; margin-left: 10px; border-radius: 5px;margin-top:5px; ">
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
        </select><br><br>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div align="right" style="padding-right: 10px;">
        <label style="font-weight:300;font-size: 15px;">Wage Income:</label>
        <input type="text" name="wage_income" id="wage_income" style="width:50%;height: 30px; margin-left: 10px; border-radius: 5px;"><br>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <div align="right" style="padding-right: 0px;">
        <input class="btn btn-info btn-submit6" type="submit" name="submit5" value="Update" onclick="move5()">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        $('.btn-submit6').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url:"modify_func.php",
                method:"POST",
                data:$('#form6').serialize(),
                success:function(data)
                {
                    document.getElementById("form6").reset();
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

here is my modify_func.php

```
    <?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","forestdb");
if(isset($_POST['dependence_of_local_people'])){
    $plantation_journal_no=$_GET['id'];
    $dependence_of_local_people=$_POST['dependence_of_local_people'];
    $wage_income=$_POST['wage_income'];
    $sql="UPDATE `benefits_derived` SET `dependence_of_local_people`='$dependence_of_local_people',`wage_income`='$wage_income' WHERE `plantation_journal_no`='$plantation_journal_no'";

    $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
}
?>
```

Comment: do you get any errors?

Comment: NO error sir... please guide me

Comment: `var_dump($result);` and show me the result.

Comment: okk sir, wait i am doing and surely i will show you the results

Comment: Note: never ever put data from user directly into SQL clauses. Start using parameters immediately. You’ll have much less problems and security issues.

Comment: if you `echo $result;` in your *modify_func.php* file, and add `alert(html);` to your `success:function()` in your `AJAX` function, what does it say?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("#form6").submit(function() {
    $.post("modify_func.php", $("#form6").serialize());
});
```

Comment: replace your click event to submit

Answer (score 0):

Just simply change your html code

```
<div align="right" style="padding-right: 0px;">
    <input class="btn btn-info btn-submit6" type="submit" 
     name="submit5" value="Update" onclick="move5()">
</div>
```

To

```
<div align="right" style="padding-right: 0px;">
    <input class="btn btn-info btn-submit6" type="button" 
     name="submit5" value="Update" onclick="move5()">
  </div>
```

And js :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('.btn-submit6').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url:"modify_func.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:$('#form6').serialize(),
            success:function(data)
            {
                document.getElementById("form6").reset();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Each time you click on submit button, open chrome devtool > `network` > `XHR` and see what happen.

Answer (score 0):

First im not sure if it is necessary to use single quotes on database column instead only in the values to be received: this is what i mean

```
UPDATE salary SET salary_id ='$salary'
```

Secondly i on if isset should receive a form submit  button name